# Automapper starting exception in Windows 8.1 Unified project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, automapper, mvvmcross

I have a cross-platform project, using mvvmcross and stuff. Right now, solution consists of Core and Windows Phone projects.

Core contains AutoMapper reference, and WP project contains AutoMapper and AutoMapper.WPA references.

Application works fine in most cases, but sometimes it throws exceptions like `Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper.Net4'`. How can i explain to that stupid AutoMapper to use AutoMapper.WPA, which is already referenced to the project? I'm using it as

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    static AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyDbModel, MyDto>();

        Mapper.AddProfile<MyProfile>();

        // Other mappings stuff            
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

and i'm calling it from Setup, which is in Shared project,

```
public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
    public Setup(Frame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
    }
    *** 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this happening while debugging? If so, you're likely showing all exceptions, instead of just uncaught exceptions. Switch to uncaught-exceptions and you should be good.

The 4.0 release of stupid AutoMapper is moving away from platform-specific extension assemblies and instead is doing compiler directives to compile into a single assembly per platform.

Comment: I can't find the "Stupid AutoMapper" NuGet package, just the normal one. How do I get this upgrade? :)

Comment: @Jimmy Bogerd I'd feel better without any unreasonable uncaught exceptions. Its okay to have different platform-dependent assemblies, but Nuget is smart enough to add .WPA81 assembly, while AutoMapper somehow tries to search for all possible versions, or something. While you answered in my question, i'd like to use this moment and thank you for lib itself - it does it's job perfectly :p